Pytube (Pytubefix) does not get all songs from YouTube-Music playlist
I have written a small programm in python to download playlists from youtube music using pytubefix. But when downloading a playlist, some songs are skipped.
For testing, I only got the relevant code and tried to print all the links in the playlist.
pl.lenght prints the correct lenght (98), but only 85 songs are counted.
So where are the 13 missing songs? They do not have anything in common that could cause an error, I think.
Copying the all the songs in the playlist to a new one only made one song appear...
from pytubefix import Playlist, YouTube

# PLaylist 2 test
url = "https://music.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRvkxIBOWuzv-mlE1zchTWO6IF1_1djlo"

pl = Playlist(url)
count = 0
for x in pl:
    print(x, end = " ")
    print(YouTube(x).title)
    count = count + 1
print(f"{pl.length} in playlist, {count} counted")


For reference: you seems to have posted this as https://github.com/JuanBindez/pytubefix/issues/365.
